# 助けてくれて有難う meaning and usage

Tags: meaning, words

I want to thank the people who are helping me on this website. Would  助けてくれて有難う be the appropriate thing to say to everyone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to thank the people who are helping me on this website.

In that case, how about...

> 「(いつも)いろいろ教えてくれてありがとう。」
>   「教えてくれてありがとう。」
>   or just 「いつもありがとう。」

If you want to sound more formal, how about...

> 「いつもお世話になってありがとうございます。」
>   「(いつも)いろいろ教えていただいて、ありがとうございます。」

---

> Would 助けてくれて有難う be the appropriate thing to say to everyone?

It would be understood, but it sounds to me like "Thank you for saving me / saving my life".

Comment: I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

That sounds more like thanks for saving me what you just wrote.

I would think 手伝ってくれてありがとうございます would sound better, which is, thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

That’s correct.

Though usually ありがとう is used instead of 有難う, if that’s your favorite, you don’t have to hesitate.

We usually use 敬語 on the Internet, so ありがとうございます is more polite and popular. But if you feel them like your friends, ありがとう isn’t bad at all.

助ける isn’t used so much in this context. 助ける is rather similar to “save, rescue”. But if you feel you’ve been saved (like you were able to make friends with Japanese and got no longer lonely), it suits.